# Ruby SecureRandom generating same result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uuid, secure-random

Have a task that generates a `uuid` for each user, we use this as a external reference code. I created a rake task to create a `PromoLink` which generates a  `uuid` for each user using rubys SecureRandom class:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  User.each { |user_id| PromoLink.create(user_id: user_id, guid: SecureRandom.uuid)}
end
```

This seemed to work only when doing some reconnaissance a few weeks later I noticed there are 18 records that have the same `uuid`, the really tricky bit is that they were not all found to be next to each other, there is some that are duplicates but 1000's of user_id's later. as you will see some `created_at` dates are a good 6.6 seconds from each other. Any Idea how this could happen, I thought that the chances of a `SecureRandom.uuid` generating a duplicate was near-impossible, so 18 duplicates seem really unfathomable.

[image: uuid-madness]

Comment: Indeed, this should be near-impossible. But we probably won't be able to tell what went wrong on your machine. Btw, now you know you should create a unique index on that uuid field.

Comment: What does `Array.new(10**6) { SecureRandom.uuid }.uniq.size` on that machine tell you?

Comment: And what Ruby version are you using?

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.3.3p222, and running that gives me `1000000` @StefanPochmann, @Sergio, that is the first thing I mentioned to them. I am just assisting in trying to come up with a reason as to what is happening.

Comment: Is maybe some *other* code *later on* changing the values?

Comment: So directly after generating these links, we fire a message to RabbitMQ that is picked up by an external system, that system then hits our API and grabs the record, it's also the external system that raised the red flag that had us do some investigation only to find out that the 18 records also sit this side, the DateTime stamps suggest they all where generated with the rake task.

Comment: Note that the first entry's `updated_at` is the same as its `created_at`, but all others got updated 12 days later (all during the same decisecond). Maybe that "update" somehow copied that first entry's guid to those other entries?

Comment: I am going to suggest we just drop the table and drop the table in the external system, add a unique constraint on the `guid` column and re-run the rake task to re-generate the `uuid` and send the whole bunch through the bus to the other system. This just made me feel uncomfortable.

Comment: @StefanPochmann you legend! thanks that is a great clue, I didn't even notice that disparity. There must be something else in this system that is writing to this table.